# undefined reference to `pow' in contiki application

Tags: contiki, cooja

[image]Is it possible to work with math.h library in contiki-cooja simulator ?. 
I am using contiki 3.0 on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I tried adding LDFLAGS += -lm in makefile of hello-world application. Moreover, i also tried adding -lm in Makefile.include file. Things don't work. What is the correct place to add -lm.

hello-world.c

```
#include "contiki.h"

#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() /
#include <math.h>
#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT
static float i;
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
PROCESS_BEGIN();
i = 2.1;
printf("Hello, world\n");
printf("%i\n", (int)pow(10,i));
printf("%i\n", (int)(M_LOG2Ei));
PROCESS_END();
}
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Makefile

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-world
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

CONTIKI = ../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
LDFLAGS += -lm
```

Comment: Can you show precisely what output you get when you run `make`? That will show which compiler options and linker options are really used.

Comment: added a screenshot of output

Answer (score 0):

First, you can added external libraries to Contiki with:

```
TARGET_LIBFILES = -lm
```

Make sure you do this before the `include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include` line, not after!

Second, which platform are you compiling for? The `msp430` platforms do not have the `pow` function in the math library. They only have the `powf` function operating on single-precision floating point numbers, and the built-in (intrinsic) function `pow` operating on integers.

If you want to operate on floating point numbers, change your code to this:

```
float f = 2.1;
pow(10, f);
```

to this

```
float f = 2.1;
powf(10, f);
```

Comment: i am compiling the program for sky platform.

Comment: Your solution worked. But there are still some issues like memory overflow. Below is the description.